# Selenium with PhantomJS gives KeyError: 'sessionId' when trying to start a session

Tags: python, macos, selenium, phantomjs

I'm trying to use Selenium (2.47.3) with PhantomJS (2.0.0) on Mac, but receive the error in the title. Python is 3.5.0.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/QuickSilver/Desktop/autocrawlerfinal.py", line 31, in <module>
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('/Users/QuickSilver/Desktop/crawler/phantomjs-2.0.0-macosx/bin/phantomjs', port=631)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/webdriver.py", line 56, in __init__
desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 87, in __init__
self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 143, in start_session
self.session_id = response['sessionId']
KeyError: 'sessionId'
```

The minimal code to reproduce is

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('/Users/QuickSilver/Desktop/crawler/phantomjs-2.0.0-macosx/bin/phantomjs', port=631)
```

The only mention of this error online mentions system proxy, but there is none and localhost is added to the exceptions anyway. What could be causing this?

Comment: Seeing the similar issue here at times. selenium==2.48.0, phantomjs=2.0.1-development, Python 2.7.10 KeyError: 139850984293008